# Dependencies on user_packages

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have in my catkin_ws/src folder two packages, A and B.

Package A depends on package B and joy on build time. I have declared at package.xml of A

```
<build_depend>B</build_depend>
<build_depend>joy</build_depend>
```

I would like to use rosdep to have users install joy automatically. However, that means that rosdep will try to download package B as well, and naturally fail.

Is there a way for rosdep to discern user packages and not search for them?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205557/dependencies-on-user_packages/) by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can tell `rosdep` to ignore packages that are already in the `src` directory, like so:

```
rosdep (check|install) --from-paths /path/to/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
```

If package `B` is already in your source workspace, `rosdep` will not try to download it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-03-21**:
It sure works. Thanks!